# String to Date in SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, date

I have the following problem:
I imported a csv file in MC and there is a date field in it. When I create the billing_date attribute as text field, all of the csv data will be imported correctly and the date will have the dd.mm.yyyy format. When I create the attribute as date field, around 2/3 of the data gets lost. In my entry data extension is the RechnungsDatum field build in as string as well.

So here is my SQL:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT (NVARCHAR, import.billing_date, 104) as RechnungsDatum
.
.
.
AND CAST(import.billing_date AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD (dd, -1, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)) AND DATEADD (dd, 0, CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))
```

I get the following error:

> Could not convert date and/or time from string data type.

Do you have an idea how exactly should i convert string to date so that my query would give a result?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data set you're trying to import has malformed dates if some of the rows loose their data and some dont. If you're unable to get a new file with correct dates or if the files are manually created i would make sure to format all rows to the same correct date formats in Excel.

You can find supported date formats for Salesforce Marketing Cloud [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_supported_date.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It turned out that the date format in the csv. file was german and the one in the MC - english per default, so i managed to upload all the data!

Comment: Good to hear! There is a famous saying in data: crap in, crap out :) make sure to mark the answer if it helped you.